# Does $n$ divide $2^{n-1} - 1$ for an infinite number of composite $n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Yes, $p$ always divides $2^{p-1}-1$ for any prime $p \ge 3$. Are there any odd composite $n$ for which $n$ divides $2^{n-1}-1$?

And on a related note, $p$ never divides $2^{p-1}+1$ for any prime $p \ge 3$. Are there any odd composite $n$ for which $n$ divides $2^{n-1}+1$?

I ask these questions because they are natural spin-offs from some well-known questions. It is well-known that no integer $n>2$ divides $2^n-1$. And it is basic to establish $p$ always divides $2^{p-1}-1$ for any prime $p \ge 3$. But for general $n$, the relationship between the integers $\varphi(n)$ and $n-1$ is not clear-cut.

Thanks for considering!

Comment: they're called *pseudoprimes*

Comment: @J.W.Tanner please elaborate?

Comment: I understand that what I asked may be a research question--or one where the answer requires pages and pages of deep mathematics...I am curious if anyone can give me any insight as to whether elementary proofs of the above are known or not.

Comment: if a composite integer $n$ divides $ 2^{n−1} − 1$, then $n$ is called a [Fermat pseudoprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime) to base $2$

Comment: Thank you @lulu !

Comment: Thanks @Tanner, I will check out pseudoprimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your first question is yes.

If a composite integer $n$ divides $ 2^{n−1} − 1$, then $n$ is called a [Fermat pseudoprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime) to base $2$.

There are infinitely many.

You could see some in the [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/A001567).